# Keeping LCD backlight On while going in sleep state

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel, devices, power-management

i am using ubuntu 18.04.4 and i am trying to use some power management related stuff.

I want to keep **laptop backlight ON** (using sysfs) while my laptop is entering into sleep, i am giving following  **echo mem  > /sys/power/state**.
How i can achieve this using static or runtime power management ???

Comment: Maybe [`vbetool dpms on`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight) would work. Do you mean hibernation(suspend to disk)? Because in that mode, the laptop actually completely shuts down and restores it's state from swap later. However suspend to ram (sleep) also cuts power, so I'm not sure if it's possible to keep anything running (also see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate)